# Change count of sliders in bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [Bxslider](http://bxslider.com/). I want to have one slider of `width: 100%` on my page when `$(window).width() < 480` and two of them when `$(window).width() >= 480`, both of `width: 50%`.
How can I do this?

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    slideWidth: 1000,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 2,
    moveSlides: 1,
    nextSelector: 'next',
    prevSelector: 'prev',
    nextText: '',
    prevText: ''
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **reload option** of bxslider
[check here](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```
window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)').addListener(function(){
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 480px)').matches){
    // initialize both of your sliders
  } else {
    // initialize only one slider
  }
})
```

Comment: I want show two sliders on page. Before width=480 two sliders_item on page (each width 50%), after width=480 (one sliders_item width 100%)